# Enum values() method unresolvable

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using Thymleaf + Spring Boot to write a table fragment, i want to loop over my enum class to print out header names.

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum ClaimColumn {
DAY("Day", null, null), WEEK("Week", null, null);
private String name;
private Function<LocalDate,Object> dateParser;
private Function<Object,String> formatter;
}
```

```
        <tr>
            <td th:each="claimColumn: ${ T(com.example.Novoferm.wrapper.ClaimColumn).values() }" \\ <-- Cannot resolve values()
                th:text="${claimColumn.name()}"
            >
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The only problem is that the method **values()** of my enum can not be resolved. I tried to look up every tutorial and documentation but it seems this case is not mentionned anywhere.

Does it have anything with the maven dependencies ?

```
        <!-- thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Does this compile?  `AllArgsContrusctor` is misspelled.  Perhaps try removing that anyway.  You also may need an `@Setter` Lombok annotation.  Also, is that the correct package name?  With a capital `N`?

Comment: Edited for misspelling. But creating a manual all args constructor does not help. I don't think a setter is needed for enum, given all attributes should be `final`. The package name is correct (although unconventional), otherwise the error would be, from the beginning, class not found.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and it keeps telling me `Cannot resolve 'values'`. However, the code does still compile and resolving the enum values also works.